# PowerShell Start-Process with other user credential and wait

Tags: powershell, wait, start-process

I am starting a process with **PowerShell** using another user with elevated rights.

```
$username = "username" 
$password = "password"
$startWithElevatedRights = "notepad"

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process powershell -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process ‘,  $startWithElevatedRights, ‘ -Wait -verb runas}'
```

I know it's bad style to write user credentials to code, but it is used within full automated procedures, so this is necessary.
My problem is, that I cannot wait until the process (last code line) finished. The inner process waits as expected.

I tried the parameter -Wait, * | Wait-Process, * | Out-Null, with return Value (which is always null)
Nothing works.

Is there any solution waiting until the process has exited?
If there is any solution for PowerShell 2.0 it would be the best for my use case.

Comment: Do you *need* to start a new powershell process within the powershell process your script already executes in in order to start notepad?

Comment: Can you post the code where you have used the -Wait parameter?

Comment: @arco444 I don't need to start another PowerShell, but I need the elevated rights. Notepad is just a dummy in this case.

Comment: @DanL I just tried it out everywhere within the line of Start-Process. After the credentials and before, after the complete argument list and within the argument list (between the ' chars)...

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the working "wait" within the inner start-process. I edited my post to match the described problem.

Comment: I don't think I can help you. I get your described behaviour with your code but when I move the -Wait after the -ArgumentList parameter my powershell waits as expected but you already mentioned you had tried this. Are you sure that it's not the process which is calling your script that is not waiting?

Comment: @DanL: I tried it again. Again it's not working. Did you change the user to one with elevated rights? Removing the change to another user, it waits (with what you meant to change), but that is useless for my use case. Nevertheless thank you for the effort.

Comment: @ToTr: I just had a bit of play with a few servers I had access to and interestingly. If I run your script (With the -Wait after the ArgumentList) at a powershell console which is already elevated it will succeed and wait.

However if the powershell.exe console is not already elevated then it doesn't wait (but still starts the secondary powershell process). On the original executing console I get an access denied error. I'm going to guess that using -Wait requires you have privileges to access the launched process which an unelevated powershell console would not be able to do.

Comment: @DanL: I tried it out too. Same behavior as you explained. **Thanks!** I'll try to find another way for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) object from `Start-Process` using `PassThru` parameter and then [wait for it to exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx).

```
$username = "username" 
$password = "password"
$startWithElevatedRights = "notepad"

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
$ps = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath powershell -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process ',  $startWithElevatedRights, ' -Wait -verb runas}'

$ps.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: I tried it out and it really works in my use cases. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and tried your solution, but seems the AZ agent cannot execute anything using specified credentials and returns ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.  User and password are fine as otherwise it returns that the user with the specific password is not found. Any idea how I can get the Azure agent to be able to execute process with specific user credentials?