# Unable to set windows service Runas from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I want to set the  windows service to run as a particular user(admin). This is my first attempt.

```
$myArgs = 'config "service22" start= demand obj= "'+$machineName+'\'+$userName+'" password= "'+$userPassword+'"'
Start-Process -FilePath sc.exe -ArgumentList $myArgs
```

I also tried this by changing the position of the variable many times(all places tried)

```
$svc = Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='service22'"
$svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$userName,$userPassword)
```

Nothing works with scripts but manually I could set it.

Comment: [You may want to look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086780/powershell-start-process-with-other-user-credential-and-wait) as far as i can see you call Start-Process the wrong way

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your second query, did you stopped and started the service for the changes to take effect

Comment: Does this return anything  `Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='service22'"`

Comment: this is what it return when I do write-host: \\vmname\root\cimv2:Win32_Service.Name="service22"

Answer (score 1):

No need to overcomplicate this.

Just:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computername -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Service -Name servicename -Credential (Get-Credential user@domain.com)
}
```

PS: Set-Service have Credential parameter in powershell v7 (tested), non in Windows Powershell

Comment: it needs to be username and password

Comment: Have you tried using it? Get-Credential will ask you for a password.

Comment: I could do that. The plan is to automate it.

Comment: It is possible. Read documentation for Get-Credential.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.1#example-6

Answer (score 0):

got the tip from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966389/how-to-change-user-credentials-of-windows-service-from-command-line)

just had to add `type=own` at the end

```
$myArgs = 'config "service22" start= demand obj= "'+$machineName+'\'+$userName+'" password= "'+$userPassword+'" type=own'
Start-Process -FilePath sc.exe -ArgumentList $myArgs
```